# Solving the integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (1+x^2)^{-3/2}$ with $\sinh$, $\cosh$?

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals, hyperbolic-functions

I want to solve the following integral:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (1+x^2)^{-3/2}$$

I thought maybe it's possible with $\sinh$ or $\cosh$ or something similar, but I can't figure it out. Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Try with $\sinh$, using the identity $\cosh^2=\sinh^2+1$.

Answer (score 6):

Write this as
\begin{equation*}
2\int^{\infty}_0 \frac{1}{(x^2+1)^{3/2}}dx.
\end{equation*}
Using the substitution $x=\tan(u)$ and the identity $1+\tan^2(u)=\sec^2(u)$ to get 
\begin{equation*}
2\int^{\pi/2}_0 \frac{1}{\sqrt{\sec^2(u)}}du=2\int^{\pi/2}_{0}\cos(u)du=2
\end{equation*}

Comment: ahh, thank you very much mate :D

Comment: Not a problem :)

Answer (score 3):

For fun I tried Yves' hyperbolic suggestion.
$$
I = \int_{-\infty}^\infty (1+x^2)^{-3/2}dx
$$
substitute $x=\sinh t$ so that $dx = \cosh t\,dt$ and
$$
I = \int_{-\infty}^\infty (\cosh^2 t)^{-3/2} \cosh t\,dt= 
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (\cosh t)^{-2} dt =
\tanh t \big|_{-\infty}^\infty = 2
$$